# ASP.NET ajax c# always returns undefined

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I searched and tried for days now but I cant find any solution. I looked up nearly every tutorial and nearly every question on this board, but no code worked for me. (I know this is a duplicate question but since no other code worked at all, you are my last hope)

I'm trying to return a `AJAX request` from C# in ASP but no matter what it always returns `undefinded` even with code from tutorials.

Here is what I have in my `Default.aspx`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "Default.aspx/GetData",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (response) {
             alert(response.d);
         },
         failure: function (response) {
             alert(response.d);
         }
     });
 });
</script>
```

and here is my codebehind from Default.aspx.cs

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetData()
{
    return "This string is from Code behind";
}
```

The Problem is: the c# method dont activate... I dont know why and I get no errormessage.

Can you pls help me?
Thanks for your advice

Comment: return JSON data instead of string, your setting dataType to json ,ajax expecting  json

Comment: Open up browser console and see response data(or error).

Comment: @AnupamSingh there are no errors in my browser console

Comment: Use `alert(response);` instead, because your response object doesn't have a property of `d`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just copy pasted your code and it worked Like a charm as one can see in the following links

[http://prntscr.com/baw6qb](http://prntscr.com/baw6mx)

I don't see what are you doing wrong, Please place a debugger in you `JAVASCRIPT` and see if its been called or Not. Rest is working fine in my Environment. There is no mismatch of `text` or no `json` instead of `string` needed. Please check you code thoroughly. you must be missing something some where
Output screenshot 
[enter link description here](http://prntscr.com/baw6qb)

Update

[image]

Comment: your links are blocked by my companies filter^^" I cant see your screenshot or code
My Javascript is called and workes, but my c# code dont run. No matter what I code in my c# function it does not run.

Is there any trick or hidden hint that I have to do in Visual studio?

Comment: as I said my dear friend I just copy past your code and it worked as you can't see the picture, let me tell you I'd a debugger placed their, and it was working. if its not calling your method in any case. can you use `firebug` to see if the request was even sent.`Net` option of the `firebug` shows you all the `methods` that execute from your page. please check that once

Comment: Firebug Message from Default.aspx/GetData: 
{"Message":"Authentication failed.","StackTrace":null,"ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"
}

Comment: Now that is your actual error `Authentication failed`

Comment: This means `User authentication hasn't been provided` or
It  failed some how`

Comment: do you've access to the page, what I mean to say is are you `authorized` user to the page

Comment: Well I just created a new ASP.NET web project, i have not changed any permissions at all. btw thank you very much for your help :D
I've tried it with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29911785/authentication-failed-error-when-calling-web-method-using-ajax solution but I got "Server Error in '/' Application.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. " with that

Comment: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` means you are sending something null and it can't take a `null` value

Comment: ahh i got it now..
I just added    `<authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>` in my Web.config and it works now

Comment: glad to know that, `remember` always debug your `javascript`

Answer (score 1):

Build format like this

```
{
    "employees":[
                  {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
                  {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
                  {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
    ]
}
```

and access through in jquery like  employees[0].firstname

Comment: where do i have to put this? I dont really know what I should do with your code

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem and it was driving me crazy. Finally, after hours of doing this and that, I checked the JSON response and it was like this :
**`{"Message":"Authentication failed.", "StackTrace":null, "ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}`**

And I searched for this issue and FINALLY found an answer over
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23033614/asp-net-calling-webmethod-with-jquery-ajax-401-unauthorized)! Hope this helps you too! :)