# AJAX not calling WebMethod ASP.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm trying to insert data to mysql without postbacks using ajax.

the following code for that is

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="SaveRecord();" /> 

<script type="text/javascript">  

                    function SaveRecord() {

                        var obj = { Year: $("#yeartxt").val(), Title: $("#titletxt").val(), Content: $("#contenttxt").val() };

                            //Jquery Ajax call to server side method  
                                     var year = $("#yeartxt").val();
                                        var title = $("#titletxt").val();
                                        var content = $("#contenttxt").val();

                                        //Jquery Ajax call to server side method  
                                        $.ajax({
                                            type: "POST",
                                            url: "Page.aspx/InsertDetails",
                                            data: "{'Year':" + year + ",'Title':" + title + ",'Content':" + content + "}",
                                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                            dataType: "json",
                                            success: function (data) {
                                                alert("Updated!");
                                            }
                                        });
                                
                    }
                </script>
```

The server side code (WebMethod) is

```
        [WebMethod]
        public static void InsertDetails(string Year, string Title, string Content)
        {
            string CoString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString;
            using (MySqlConnection CoN = new MySqlConnection(CoString))
            {
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO db(year, title, content) VALUES(@year, @title, @content)", CoN))
                {
                    CoN.Open();
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", Year);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", Title);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Content", Content);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
```

However, the WebMethod is not being called (I tried debugging it). I tried playing around the code. Nothing worked. The alert in `success: function (data) { alert("Updated!"); }` is working, this probably indicates that there's nothing wrong with the ajax code, I suppose.

I need help with that, or an alternative for inserting data to mysql without a postback. That is my focus.

Thank you.

Comment: Check the network tab in dev tools after you make the AJAX request to see the response text and status code. It should give you an error you can use to figure out what the problem is and debug it

Comment: Thank you for your response. I checked it and the error was {Message: "Authentication failed.", StackTrace: null,…}
ExceptionType: "System.InvalidOperationException"

Comment: In which case you need to include the authentication token for the current user within the request - whatever method it is you're using. For example, a Bearer or basic auth token would go in a header.

Comment: I actually tried modifying the RouteConfig according to the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29911785/authentication-failed-error-when-calling-web-method-using-ajax it gave another error Message: "Invalid JSON primitive: undefined.",…}
ExceptionType: "System.ArgumentException"